# Mandrill multi recipient with variable subject

Tags: node.js, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill-api for Nodejs.

When creating a message for multiple recipients I can create `merge_vars` for each one of them, but is there a way to give each recipient a different **subject**. Im sending invoices, and would like to have a subject like: "Invoice X", where X is a invoice number =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use merge tags in the subject line, and then pass recipient-specific subject lines. A lot of people use this to personalize the subject line for each recipient with their name, for example. So you could pass the subject as `Invoice *|INVOICENO|*` - if you're already putting the invoice number in the email content with a merge tag, just use the same merge tag in the subject.

Comment: Please Note the typo in the inline code block. I can't edit it